# Djangoのチェックボックスで送信した後にメッセージが表示される方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, django

この画像のようにchecked! not checked!と表示したいのですが、clickボタンを押して送信してもこの表示だけされません。どうすれば表示できますか？

[image]
HelloViewクラスを書いているviews.pyのコードは以下です。

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import HelloForm

class HelloView(TemplateView):

    def __init__(self):
        self.params = {
            'title': 'Hello',
            'form': HelloForm(),
            'result': None
        }
    
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'hello/index.html', self.params)
    
    def post(self, request):
        ch = request.POST['check']
        self.params['result'] = 'selected: "' + ch + '".'
        self.params['form'] = HelloForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'hello/index.html', self.params)
```

index.htmlのコードは以下です。

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-primary">{{title}}</h1>
    <p class="h5 mt-4">{{message|safe}}</p>
    <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <tr><td></td></tr>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2" value="click">
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

forms.pyのコードは以下です。

```
from django import forms

class HelloForm(forms.Form):
    check = forms.BooleanField(label='Checkbox', required=False)
```

urls.pyのコードは以下です。

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import HelloView

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', HelloView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

Comment: チェックボックスの表示内容は `{{ form.as_p }}` で実現していますが、この内容は`HelloView`クラスを見る必要があります。まずは、質問文を編集して `HoView`の内容も記載してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。気づきませんでした。ご指摘の通り編集してHelloViewクラスを書いたコードも冒頭に記載しました。10/25